# How to switch between JLayeredPane s inside single JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jlayeredpane

I have a JFrame extended class like

```
public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {}
```

Inside this, I have 3 `JLayeredPane`s like;

```
JLayeredPane layera = new JLayeredPane();
JLayeredPane layera = new JLayeredPane();
JLayeredPane layera = new JLayeredPane();
```

I have a constructor, where I add components to my layers like;

```
MyClass(){
    layera.add(buttona);
    layerb.add(buttonb);
    layerc.add(buttonc)
}
```

All the layers have same height and width of parent JFrame, so as to fill the frame and to completely mask other layers.

I am adding all the layers to frame at once. There will be a topmost layer (layera) with button, and other layers lies beneath this layer, not visible to user. When user click on the button in that layer, the user should be presented with layerb (hiding layera and buttona), which is having a button. When user click on that button, he should get layerc and buttonc. Again, if user click on that, he should get layera and buttona.

I have set all layers as opaque, so that it hides other layers.

The entire code may looks like;

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLayeredPane layera = new JLayeredPane();
    JLayeredPane layerb = new JLayeredPane();
    JLayeredPane layerc = new JLayeredPane();

    JButton buttona = new JButton("buttona");
    JButton buttonb = new JButton("buttonb");
    JButton buttonc = new JButton("buttonc");

    MyClass(){

        layera.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        layerb.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        layerc.setBounds(0,0,100,100);

        buttona.setBounds(30,30,40,30);
        buttonb.setBounds(30,30,40,30);
        buttonc.setBounds(30,30,40,30);

        layera.add(buttona);
        layerb.add(buttonb);
        layerc.add(buttonc);

        layera.setOpaque(true);
        layerb.setOpaque(true);
        layerc.setOpaque(true);

        add(layera);
        add(layerb);
        add(layerc);

        setSize(100,100);
        setLayout(null); 
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        flag = 0;
        String name =  e.getActionCommand();

        if(name.equals("buttona")){         
            //show layerb           
        }else if(name.equals("buttonb")){
            //show layerc
        }else{
            //show layera
        }
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        new MyClass();  
    }

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `equals(...)` to compare `String`s instead of `==`, eg: `if(name.equals("buttona")){...}`

Comment: Why?  You could probably use a single `JLayeredPane` and get the same result? To make switching between different views, you should be using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)